# I would like to know if there is a way to put a libgdx game inside an Android app?

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to put a libgdx game inside an Android app?

like mini-games in talking tom, pou...

I created some games in libgdx and now I want to put them in this app... I don't know how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "put them inside the app", you could just check if it is installed on the phone and start them if they are, and send them to a link to download them if not

Comment: I mean that I would put them in the same application package... in this way the user should only download the app

Comment: You are more likely to need to put your app into the game.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is make an uber-app, which basically contain a menu, where user select which game to play with, and start that game when user makes a selection from the menu. If user ends one game, app should return to the menu. I think that's doable.

Comment: Its doable in `Swing` with an `LwjglCanvas`.  Maybe android's got something similar...you should ask the devs on the libgdx forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a screen include some button for select a game.

- if you wanna implement it on libgdx:

  you most use 'Screen class' instand of 'Game class' for each game and have a   screen for select game. you can learn about screen (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game)
- if you have native android app and wanna put libgdx game on it:

  check links :

  - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx ,
  - [LibGDX inside Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711995/libgdx-inside-android-activity)
- and if you want use some android native (like Bluetooth) you most use interface in game and implement it on android code

I hope be useful.