# Android: start an AndroidApplication class

Tags: java, android, android-application-class

In my activity I want to start a class which extends an AndroidApplication class but I don't know how to do it. I want to call the onCreate method of the AndroidApplication class, of course.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    new AndroidLauncher();
}
}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.utente.morramongame"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">

    <application
        android:name=".AndroidLauncher">
    </application>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: register it in manifest application tag

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh and then?

Comment: `onCreate` is automatically called if you set the Application up correctly

Comment: `Application` is created by the framework.  You never create it or any other Android component yourself.

Comment: Also see: [Why create an Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-extend-an-application-class)

Comment: @cricket_007 should I define it as an activity in the manifest too?

Comment: No, it's an `application`. You already have a tag for that around all your activities. That other post clearly explains what to do. Also, the description in the documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I posted the manifest

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to say. I will edit the other post.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did it but all the things in Application class aren't called

Comment: If you put `android:name` within the `<application` tag, then they should be called. If you edit your question again with what you have, then we can re-open it

Comment: remove nested `application` tag and add `android:name=".AndroidLauncher"`  after `android:label="@string/app_name"`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I have this error: AndroidLauncher isn't assignable to Android.app.Application

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh my class doesn't extend Application but AndroidApplication

Comment: @cricket_007 see

Comment: @cricket_007 I was talking about AndroidApplication not Application, they are very different and so it isn't duplicate. I solved the problem with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711995/libgdx-inside-android-activity

Comment: And why not? Even the answer there says *The issue was that I hadn't declared my "Bobble" class/file in the AndroidManifest file*

Comment: If you had defined [**AndroidApplication**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java#L61)  more clearly, then, I would not have closed. I apologize. It **is** an activity, so, yes it would need an `<activity>` tag, but besides that point, you have an error with the XML shown here. It is `<application android:name=".YourApplication" android:allowBackup="true"`... You already had an application tag, and there is only one, so it's not clear why you added another